# Unable to add object to an array in my state React.js

Tags: reactjs, redux, lodash

So in my state I want to keep track of an array which will contain objects used for a query. Im using React.js with Redux and have lodash package. The problem is that I seem to fail to add an object to my array in my state.

I hope someone can tell me how to do this properly.

Here is my function:

```
setFilterActive(type, min, max) {
const filterObj = {
  type: type,
  min: min,
  max: max
};
let state = this.state;
_.reject(state.queryObject.query.filters, filter => filterObj.isEqual(filter));
_.merge(filterObj,state.queryObject.query.filters);
console.log(filterObj);
this.setState(state);
console.log("Filters Array:" , this.state.queryObject.filters);
}
```

Comment: Not an answer to of your question, but if you are using redux in react you shouldn't be using the component's state.

Comment: @OriolBG I don't think that is true. State is still fine to use, but any state you have should probably be localized. Saying you shouldn't EVER use state is unnecessary. You would still use it for input fields just to name one thing.

Comment: Sorry, that came out wrong. Just that in this case seems like the array is something that really matters to the application.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
  setFilterActive(type, min, max) {
    const filterObj = {
      type: type,
      min: min,
      max: max
    };
    let queryObject = this.state.queryObject;
    _.reject(queryObject.query.filters, filter => filterObj.isEqual(filter));
    let newQueryObject = _.merge(filterObj,queryObject.query.filters);
    console.log(filterObj);
    this.setState({queryObject:newQueryObject});
    console.log("Filters Array:" , this.state.queryObject.filters);
  }
```

Also as a suggestion you should use `_.assign` rather than `_.merge` since it mutates the object.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but my the array in the state is not updated with the queryobject :(

Comment: In the end, I managed to store the variable in the state could be a bug in my build eventually